# Unable to create the Patch Version for the Second Generation Managed Package

Tags: apex, managed-package, appexchange, second-generation-packaging, patch

Unable to create Patch Version: This is the error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION : UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: Managed Package Patch Modification Exception: A change was made to the patch release that will change the visible behavior of the application: Component can't be created because it will be automatically included in the package.

Changes I made in new version:

- Changed the Parameters of AuraEnabled methods
- Added a new AuraEnabled variable to the inner class (wrapper class) which is used as return type of a AuraEnabled method
- Added a public static variable to a public class
- Changed the Custom Metadata Type record whose fields are upgradable
- Added a lightning progress bar in an LWC Component Conditionally based on a variable (using if:true)

Comment: Are you sure that no other components got added accidentially? Also, in terms of the LWC changes, did you add any `@api` properties and/or try to change the target property configuration at all?

Comment: Hi @Phil W, I am sure that I have only added few track variables not the api variables, and changed the visibility of few components based on few boolean variables by using template if:true directive.

Comment: Did you need to add an extra import for `track` annotation? Also, do you really need the `track`? These are only needed if you want to track changes to arrays or complex object properties, not for simple Booleans etc.

Comment: Changes to LWCs in patches are possible (we've done it) but you have to be cautious as to exactly what changes you make. Changing anything around targets and target properties is a no-no for sure (we got hit by this one - and have found this to be troublesome even in major/minor releases).

Comment: Yes @Phil W, I have changed the label of an aura design attribute, it is still indicating the same error even after reverting the changes. We have accidently opened the renderer, css files of aura component, so a separate file has been created in new patch version. Is this be the reason?

Comment: Yes, very probably. Remove those new files if you can.

Comment: Ok @Phil W, "Changes to LWCs in patches are possible", Does this mean we can add new divs in LWC's and control its visibility based on boolean variables using if:true directives?

Comment: For sure you can update the template and I am 99% sure we have specifically added extra properties (not `@api` or `@track`) to change template behaviour in a patch.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Phil W, I am able to create the patch version including the changes in the LWC. The error is due to the additional files added in Aura Component.

Comment: You should provide a self-answer to explain which files were accidentally added to the aura component and how that happened!

Comment: Yes @PhilW, I have answered the question. We have another problem regarding the Custom Metadata Type record. I have posted the question.  Could you please help us.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/414201/how-to-restrict-users-accessing-the-custom-metadata-type-record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why we couldn't create patch version is we have accidently opened the renderer and css files of an aura component. So a separate CSS and Renderer file has been created for the Aura Component. After manually deleting those files in sfdx project, we were able to create the patch version.